# YooTheme WidgetKit non Joomla

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, joomla, joomla-widgetkit

I want to make a simple html without Joomla but I like from WidgetKit the [slideshow plugin](http://yootheme.com/widgetkit).

I like that there is a slideshow with style pace_tabs where it shows the image in top big and then in boxes underneath the title of an image. Like in the screenshot

[image]

It has the functionality when you click the box or image text to show corresponding image. Also autoplays and the box that is currently showing has a different background (like hover effect)

Is it possible to add this in an html template without joomla?
Is there maybe something similar form another js/jquery library that does this effect?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using UIkit...

http://getuikit.com/docs/slideshow.html

The new Widgetkit uses Uikit as a base for the functionality and Uikit doesn't rely on Joomla etc.

It can be used anywhere by simply building the markup.